# Uncaught TypeError for javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting the this message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null" for this `linesplitted = elements[i].nextSibling.nodeValue.split("||");` The code is in below. I will appreciate your input to solve this. The code has worked before. I think it is something about new php oder jquery...

```
    $('#r_NEStd').hide(); // Das Feld ist am Anfang versteckt und duch klicken 
auf NE wird wieder gezeigt.
$("input[name='x_Posten[]'], input[name='x_NE[]']").click(function() { // 
    Field2 has multiple inputs(checkboxes) so they should be selected by name
    document.getElementById("x_Total").readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("x_Auslagen").readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("x_RBetrag").readOnly = true;
    if ($("input[name='x_Posten[]']:checked").val() &&
        $("input[name='x_NE[]']:checked").val()) { // WENN NichtErhaeltlichkeit und 
        Posten geklickt sind
        document.finvoicesadd.x_Total.value = '';

        var Anzahl = 0;
        var Auslagen = 0;
        var AuslagenMwSt = 0;
        var Total = 0;
        var splitted;
        var nestdsatz = document.finvoicesadd.x_NEStd.value;
        var e = document.getElementById("x_Vorschuss");
        var VorschussValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var nestdsatz = document.finvoicesadd.x_NEStd.value;
        var elements = document.getElementsByName("x_Posten[]");
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].checked) {
                splitted = elements[i].nextSibling.nodeValue.split("||");
                Auslagen = Auslagen + +parseFloat(splitted[4]);
                AuslagenMwSt = AuslagenMwSt + +(parseFloat(splitted[4]) *
                    (1 + parseFloat(splitted[5])));
                Anzahl = Anzahl + +parseFloat(splitted[2]);
                Total = Total + +(parseFloat(splitted[2] * nestdsatz) *
                    (1 + parseFloat(splitted[5])));
            }
        }
        document.finvoicesadd.x_Auslagen.value = Auslagen.toFixed(2);
        document.finvoicesadd.x_Total.value = (Total + AuslagenMwSt).toFixed(2);
        document.finvoicesadd.x_RBetrag.value = (Math.round(((Total +
            AuslagenMwSt) - VorschussValue) * 20, 0) / 20).toFixed(2);
        document.finvoicesadd.x_Vorlage.value = "rechnungne";

    } else { // WENN x_Posten oder NE nicht oder nur ein Feld gelickt ist
        document.finvoicesadd.x_Total.value = '';
        var Anzahl = 0;
        var Auslagen = 0;
        var Total = 0;
        var splitted;
        var e = document.getElementById("x_Vorschuss");
        var VorschussValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var nestdsatz = document.finvoicesadd.x_NEStd.value;
        var elements = document.getElementsByName("x_Posten[]");
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].checked) {
                splitted = elements[i].nextSibling.nodeValue.split("||");
                // Auslagen = Auslagen+ +(parseFloat(splitted[4])* 
                (1 + parseFloat(splitted[5])));
            Auslagen = Auslagen + +parseFloat(splitted[4]);
            Anzahl = Anzahl + +parseFloat(splitted[3]);
            Total = Total + +parseFloat(splitted[6]);
        }
    }
    document.finvoicesadd.x_Auslagen.value = Auslagen.toFixed(2);
    document.finvoicesadd.x_Total.value = (Total).toFixed(2);
    document.finvoicesadd.x_RBetrag.value = (Math.round(((Total) -
        VorschussValue) * 20, 0) / 20).toFixed(2);
    document.finvoicesadd.x_Vorlage.value = "rechnung";
}
});
```

Comment: Do you know what the error means?

Comment: log your nodeValue to check if it has value or not or it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
if (elements[i].checked) {
```

with this:

```
debugger;
if (elements[i].checked && elements[i].nextSibling.nodeValue != null) {
```

This will solve the error, although I have no idea which repercussions it will have on your program.

The error is given by the fact that `elements[i].nextSibling.nodeValue` is null when you're checking it.

Comment: Hi Saturnix, thank you for your input. Now the error is disappeared but the function is not working. That means I am not getting the totals... Do you have an idea?

Comment: elements[i].nextSibling.nodeValue is null. Write "debugger" in the line above the if, open with Chrome dev tools open (F12), reload the page and hover your mouse over nextSibling to see what's inside of it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. The error is now disappeared but the output such Total and other calculations are not working. Is there a way to check if the coding and logic is correct? Was was working formerly without any problem. I think this is something with new version of jquery to do. Any input where to start?

Comment: I am getting this messega in consol: [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 72ms jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2   ..